# extern keyword usage

Tags: c++, keyword, extern

I have three programs in which I am using `extern` keyword. I am not able to understand the result. Below are three examples:

Example 1: I was expecting that below code will give compilation error that multiple declaration of `k`. But it works fine?

```
int k; //works fine
extern int k = 10;

void main()
{
    cout<<k<<endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Example 2: When I am trying to initialize "k" in above example compiler gives error. Why?

```
int k = 20; //error
extern int k = 10;

void main()
{
    cout<<k<<endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Example 3: In this example I changed the order of definitions mentioned in example 1. When I compile this code I am getting errors. Why?

```
extern int k = 10;
int k;   //error

void main()
{
    cout<<k<<endl;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: +1 for example 3. Also, 1st example is not a good practice

Comment: C or C++? `int k;` at file scope means different things in these two languages.

Answer (score 10):

**Example 2**: You are trying to initialize a global variable twice, with two different values. This is the error.

**Example 3**: You first declare an `extern` variable, and then define a variable with the same name in the same compilation unit. This is *not* possible.

Comment: The reasoning which u have given for Example 3 is not applicable for Example 1 also ?  I should get error even in Example 1.

Comment: @anu: In example 1, you declare them the other in the reverse order: at the time the compiler creates the external variable, I does not know that the actual variable will be in the same compiler unit.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `**extern**` keyword the way it meant to be used which is to reference something that is out of the current scope.

You should also follow the rules that works in every compiler and not try to use anomalies of some compiler, your examples gave me lot of errors in my own compiler.

#### Rules are:

1. Use `extern` to reference and not to define a variable.
2. Use some sort of convention for external naming. I put all my externals as  capitals, so when I see something like `MYVAR` I know its a global.
3. Put all of your externals in an include header(.h) file  and do an `#include` in your cpp files, this way is more convenient and helps to unclutter your source code.

---

See this example where I use all 3 rules:

#### My **module1.cpp** file:

```
unsigned short int AGLOBAL = 10; // definer and initializer

void MyFunc(void)
{
  AGLOBAL+=1; // no need to include anything here cause is defined above
  // more .....    
}
```

#### My Header file **globals.h:**

```
// this is to include only once
#ifndef MYH
#define MYH
extern unsigned short int AGLOBAL; // no value in here!

#endif
```

#### Other **module2.cpp** file:

```
#include globals.h

char SomeOtherFunc(void)
{
  AGLOBAL+=10; // ok cause its declared by globals.h
  // do more....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The use of `extern` keyword is to tell the compiler that:

> The variable is defined externally.

The first program should give you an error. Which compiler are you using? BTW, `void main()` is not standard. Neither in C nor in C++.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2008. Well its just learning hence i ignored return type of main. BTW thanks for info.

Comment: @anu, OK. If it is for learning, then it is much better off using more standards compliant compiler for eg. VS2010 Express Edition ( free) , g++ latest versions.

Answer (score 5):

Your compiler is sloppy.  Compiling this trivial variation (including the header and `using` declaration), I get:

```
$ cat xxx.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int k; //works fine
extern int k = 10;

void main()
{
cout<<k<<endl;
getchar();
}
$ g++ -c  xxx.cpp
xxx.cpp:5:12: warning: ‘k’ initialized and declared ‘extern’ [enabled by default]
xxx.cpp:5:12: error: redefinition of ‘int k’
xxx.cpp:4:5: error: ‘int k’ previously declared here
xxx.cpp:7:11: error: ‘::main’ must return ‘int’
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.6.0
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$
```

Which compiler are you using?

Comment: +1 similar code will throw error for a regular c program on gcc (GCC) 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1).

Answer (score 2):

```
int k;
extern int k = 10;
```

This is ok in C, where you can have a "tentative definition" in addition to the real one. In C++ it is not allowed. There it is an attempt to declare the same variable twice.

My C compiler also warns me that having both `extern` and an initialization at the same time is unusual.

```
int k = 20; //error
extern int k = 10;
```

This attempts to give `k` two different values, which of course doesn't work.

```
extern int k = 10;
int k;   //error
```

This seems to be equivalent to case 1. It is not allowed in C++, but seems to be acceptable in C99.

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: Gives an **[Redefinition Error in c++(gcc-4.3.4)](http://ideone.com/LctxL)**

Case 2: Gives an **[Redefinition Error in c++(gcc-4.3.4)](http://ideone.com/XkuQ1)**

Case 3: Gives an **[Redefinition Error in c++(gcc-4.3.4)](http://ideone.com/ja7nU)**

In all the three cases You try to **define** a variable named `k` with external linkage  and you try to **define** another variable named `k` in the same scope, this generates a Redefinition error.

**Reference:**
***C++ Standard: 3.1 Declarations and definitions***

```
3 [Example: all but one of the following are definitions:

int a; // defines a
extern const int c = 1; // defines c
int f(int x) { return x+a; } // defines f and defines x
......
```

In the above snippet `a` & `c` both are definitions.

If your compiler does not give you an error for all the three cases, then it is broken as far as C++ is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

For the third one, you really want this

```
extern int k = 10;
extern int k;   //okay: this is just a declaration. 
// extern int k = 4;  re-define is no good.

void main()
{
cout<<k<<endl;
getchar();
}
```

You can only define a variable once. You may declare as many times as you like, however.

---

To indicate a bit further, `int i;` is both declaration and definition. Often time intiizliation is thought as "definition". For an autotmatic variable, both declaration and definition is done in one single statement.

So when we define `int k;` memory has been allocated whose name reference is "k". Hence, linker will complain when you try to redefine it.

```
int k;
extern int k = 3;  // already defined in the previous statement
```

Hence, this is also a compilation error

```
extern int k = 3;
int k;    // trying to redefine again - bad
```

This is probably applied to only in C++. I am not familiar with C, therefore, I can't speak of C. In C++, even my solution will complain, but will not throw error at it.

Please judge me and correct my mistakes. I am learning also.

Comment: `<stdin>:2: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘k’ with no type`

Comment: @CharlesBailey thanks. I missed the int in the 2nd statement. This definitely works :D

Answer (score 2):

I understand Examples 2 and 3. But the fact that Example 1 was compiled is so weird. gcc would never compiled such code.

Answer (score 1):

First, a nit pick. You are talking about global variable resolution. This is the job of the *linker* and not the compiler. While it no real implications since all compiler suites are usually executed with the linker as well.

What you should know about global variables is that they are of two kinds: weak and strong. Since there can only be one variable with a given name, if there are multiple definitions, the linker must figure out which one to use. If there are multiple string definitions, then there is an error. If there is a single strong definition then it is chosen as the canonical one and all other definitions refer to it. If there are only weak definitions then one of them gets promoted.

Any declaration where the variable has a value assigned to it is considered strong. Also, if there is no assignment then the `extern` keyword will force the variable to refer to another variable if one exists (in effect making the weakest of the weak).

Case 1: You have a weak declaration followed by a strong one. This is cool.
Case 2: You have two strong declarations. Error!
Case 3: You have a strong declaration followed by a weak one. I'm not actually sure why this one fails. If I were to guess I would say that the second declaration is being treated as strong by the the linker.